# Eventhandler for classnames is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Let user create category **(done)**
2. Add that category to local storage **(done)**
3. Add that category to a list on the screen **(done)**
4. Attach an event to that category, so when a user clicks on it, it will show all the posts in that category.

I want to have 1 function (or eventlistener, whatever you want to call it) that handles all the clicks. It has to know for which category it has to sort some posts and that is the point where I am stuck.
This is my code that does step 1 and 2:

```
    document.getElementById("newCategoryButton").onclick = function () 
    {
    var input = document.getElementById("newCategoryInput");

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "<a href='#' id='sort" + input.value + "'>" + input.value + "</a></li>";
    localStorage.setItem(input.value, input.value);
    document.getElementById("categories").appendChild(li);

    }
```

This is the code for step 3. The important stuff happens at the **else**

```
 for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (localStorage.key(i).indexOf("formObject") > -1) {
                var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
                addRow(value);
            } else {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.className = "category";
                li.innerHTML = "<a href='#' id='sort" + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) + "'>" + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) + "</a></li>";
                document.getElementById("categories").appendChild(li);
```

And this is the code for step 4:

```
var categories = document.getElementsByClassName("category");
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; ++i) {
    categories[i].addEventListener("Click", SortPosts(categories[i].textContent));
}

function SortPosts(value)
{
    alert(value);
    //Sort coding here
}
```

When the page loads, it automatically alerts the value of SortPosts(), without clicking on anything. What is wrong with my code? Also, am I giving all the categories click events or am I doing that wrong, as well?

Comment: The `SortPosts` function doesn't return a reference to the function to be used as an event handler. [Basics, basics...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: I would also suggest adding the event to the class 'category' and use something like `event.target.id` to specify functionality of that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the line:

```
 categories[i].addEventListener("Click", SortPosts(categories[i].textContent));
```

you are calling the function Sort posts and binding the result to the click event. try this:

```
categories[i].addEventListener("Click", function(i){
    return function(){
         SortPosts(categories[i].textContent);
    }
}(i));
```

note the closure around the i variable to keep it in scope

Edit: it occured to me after submitting this, while the code is fairly compact, it is not particularly easy to read especially if you are not familiar wih closures, so here is a slightly more verbose, easier to read version:

```
categories[i].addEventListener("Click", getPostSorter(i));


function getPostSorter(i) {
    return function(){
         SortPosts(categories[i].textContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can get the textContent after the function is called.

```js
function MyEvents(){
var categories = document.getElementsByClassName("category");
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; ++i) {
    categories[i].addEventListener("click", SortPosts,false);
}
}
function SortPosts(){
    alert(event.target.textContent);
    //Sort coding here
} 
window.onload=MyEvents;
```

```html
<div class="category">Click for category one</div>
<div class="category">Click for category two</div>
```